# Identifying lattice squares that are intersected by a closed curve

Tags: regions, intersection, lattices

Given a lattice of unit squares I would like to find the number of squares that a curve (in the example below the curve is a circle) passes through and the number of squares that totally reside inside the curve.

In the example the number of squares that the curve passes through is 60 and the number that are fully within the curve is 156. These are the two numbers I would like to generate.

I have created a graphic of the situation with the following code.

```
grid = Table[{x, y}, {x, -8, 8, 1}, {y, -8, 8, 1}];
centres = Table[{x, y}, {x, -7.5, 7.5, 1}, {y, -7.5, 7.5, 1}];
g1 = Graphics@Line[#] & /@ grid;
g2 = Graphics@Line[#] & /@ Transpose@grid;
g3 = Graphics[{Red, PointSize[0.005], Point /@ centres}];
g4 = Graphics[Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[59]]];
g5 = Graphics[{Black, PointSize[0.0075], Point@{0, 0}}];
Show[g1, g2, g3, g4, g5, Frame -> False, 
 PlotRange -> {{-9, 9}, {-9, 9}}, AspectRatio -> 1]
```

which produces:

[image: lattice]

I am not sure how to set such a thing up - I have looked in the documentation but I am not seeing something similar at all.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Just to make it clear: Intersection is valid only if the curve passes through the square (therefore it has two intersections with squares' boundary), not if it only touches the square in one point, right?

Comment: @Domen Yes that is correct - just touching doesn't count. Which is why I made the radius of the circle in the example the square root of a prime of the form 4k+3 so it wasn't the sum of two squares.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```
rectangles = Rectangle /@ Tuples[Range[-8, 7, 1], {2}]

Count[_?(Not @ RegionDisjoint[Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[59]], #] &)] @ rectangles
```

> ```
> 60
> ```

```
Count[_?(RegionWithin[Disk[{0, 0}, Sqrt[59]], #] &)] @ rectangles
```

> ```
> 156
> ```

**Update:** To exclude rectangles "just touching" the circle, we can use

```
Count[_?(FreeQ[_EmptyRegion | _Point]@
  RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[59]], #] &)] @ rectangles
```

> ```
> 60
> ```

```
Count[_?(FreeQ[_EmptyRegion | _Point]@
     RegionIntersection[Circle[{0, 0}, Sqrt[53]], #] &)] @ rectangles
```

> ```
> 52
> ```

Comment: Thank you for that - nice and brief. But I do have a question - if I choose a radius of root 53 there are eight points (-7,-2),(-7,2),(7,-2),(7,2), (-2,-7),(-2,7),(2,-7) and (2,7) where the circle touches those points - but then the first count is 68 and not 52. It is counting the two squares that touch each of those points and thus adding 16 to the total. How can I reject those situations and just count the squares where the curve actually crosses into a square?

Comment: @1729taxi, please see the update.

Comment: Fantastic. This is the sort of thing I have never done in Mathematica - your help is much appreciated. I shall accept this answer.

Comment: If I make my square a curve (of side length 7) then the second returned number should be zero - _Point does not work then - I tried replacing with _Line and it just gives the result of 4 - do you know how to detect this situation but return the correct number of zero?

Answer (score 5):

### Edit

For `r=Sqrt[53]`, there are `148` squares in the curve, and there are `56` outside the curve, and `16*16-148-56=52` on the curve.

```
Clear["Global`*"];
lines0 = 
 Flatten[{Table[
    Line[{{i, j}, {i, j} + {1, 0}}], {i, -8, 7}, {j, -8, 8}], 
   Table[Line[{{i, j}, {i, j} + {0, 1}}], {i, -8, 8}, {j, -8, 7}]}];
p = {0, 0};
r = Sqrt[53];
range1 = Disk[p, r];
range2 = Annulus[p, {r, 4 r}];
intersec[range_] := Module[{lines, pts, edges, g, faces, squares},
   lines = 
    Cases[RegionIntersection[range, #] & /@ lines0, _Line, Infinity];
   pts = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[lines[[;; , 1]], {2, 1}]];
   edges = 
    Table[UndirectedEdge @@ Flatten[FirstPosition[pts, #] & /@ d], {d,
       lines[[;; , 1]]}];
   g = Graph[edges, 
     VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Range@Length@pts -> pts]];
   faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
   squares = Select[faces, Length[#] == 4 &];
   {MeshRegion[pts, Polygon /@ squares], Length[squares]}];
Labeled[Graphics[{lines0, {FaceForm[], EdgeForm[Cyan], 
    range1}, {FaceForm[Yellow], EdgeForm[Red], 
    intersec[range2] // First}, {FaceForm[Green], EdgeForm[Red], 
    intersec[range1] // First}}], {Style[intersec[range1] // Last, 
   Green, 20], Style[intersec[range2] // Last, Darker@Yellow], 
  Style[2*8*2*8 - intersec[range1][[2]] - intersec[range2][[2]], 
   20]}]
```

[image]

**Original**

- Similar with https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/280656/72111, we list all of the segments, and intersection such lines with a region.
- Then we construct a `Planar Graph` and calculate all the 4-cycles.

```
lines0 = 
  Flatten[{Table[
     Line[{{i, j}, {i, j} + {1, 0}}], {i, -8, 7}, {j, -8, 8}], 
    Table[Line[{{i, j}, {i, j} + {0, 1}}], {i, -8, 8}, {j, -8, 7}]}];
Manipulate[Module[{range, lines, pts, edges, g, faces, squares},
  range = Disk[p, Sqrt[59]];
  (* range=Annulus[p,{3,Sqrt[59]}]; *)
  lines = 
   Cases[RegionIntersection[range, #] & /@ lines0, _Line, Infinity];
  pts = DeleteDuplicates[Flatten[lines[[;; , 1]], {2, 1}]];
  edges = 
   Table[UndirectedEdge @@ Flatten[FirstPosition[pts, #] & /@ d], {d, 
     lines[[;; , 1]]}];
  g = Graph[edges, 
    VertexCoordinates -> Thread[Range@Length@pts -> pts]];
  faces = PlanarFaceList[g];
  squares = Select[faces, Length[#] == 4 &];
  Labeled[
   Show[Graphics[lines0], 
    Graphics[{EdgeForm[Cyan], FaceForm[], range, EdgeForm[Red], 
      FaceForm[Green], MeshRegion[pts, Polygon /@ squares]}], 
    PlotRange -> 10], Framed@Length@squares]], {{p, {0, 0}}, Locator, 
  Appearance -> None}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent - I'll look through this in more detail later - family wedding this weekend is taking up my time. I do appreciate this. I went ahead and accepted kglr's answer primarily through brevity but, again, thanks for your food for thought.